# Access variables inside methods in a Spock Testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, spock, stub

In Spock testing, I would like to be able to change the values of the variables inside the method.
For example, I would like to change the value of uName to 'John'.  or for another test, change the value of uCat to "seller" when doing the testing.  How can I make sure in the testing that the 2 methods: postComment and sendEmails inside the else statements get executed.

```
class userService {

    void userComment()
    {
        def uName = "test123"   
        def uCat = Category.getUserCategory(uName)

        if (uCat.empty){    
            println("no categories to process")
        }
        else
        {
            postComment(uName)
            batchJob.sendEmail(uName)   
        }
    }
}



class userServiceSpec extends Specification{
    def "test userComment"()
    {   
        given:
        ?????

        when:   
        ?????

        then:
        1 * postComment(_)

        then:
        1* batchJob.sendEmail(_)
    }
}
```

Comment: Bad news for you: You cannot change local variables in a test - and you shouldn't! A class or method should be a black box for your test. Redesign your application for decoupling and [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), then you can just inject dependencies like user name or batch job. The problem is not the test but that the application is not testable because it creates its own dependencies internally instead of getting them injected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `uName`, you need to inject the username as a constructor param or add a method param in your service.  A method param probably makes the most sense.

Because you made `getUserCategory` a static method, you have to use [`GroovySpy`](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1-rc-3/all_in_one.html#_mocking_static_methods) but it's usually an indication you're doing something wrong.  You should really make a `CategoryService` that is injected into your `userService`

```
class userService {

    void userComment(uName)
    {  
        def uCat = Category.getUserCategory(uName)

        if (uCat.empty){    
            println("no categories to process")
        }
        else
        {
            postComment(uName)
            batchJob.sendEmail(uName)   
        }
    }
}


class userServiceSpec extends Specification{
    def userService = Spy(userService)
    def CategorySpy = GroovySpy(Category, global: true)

    def "test userComment"()
    {   
        given:
        def uName = "test123"  

        when: 'we have a category found'  
        userService.userComment(uName)

        then: 'return user cat of "seller" '
        1 * CategorySpy.getUserCategory(uName) >> 'seller'
        1 * postComment(uName)

        then:
        1 * batchJob.sendEmail(uName)

        when: 'we have an "empty" category'  
        userService.userComment(uName)

        then: 'return a category where uCat.empty will be true'
        1 * CategorySpy.getUserCategory(uName) >> []
        0 * postComment(uName)
        0 * batchJob.sendEmail(uName)
    }
}
```

Some [Spock Framework slides](https://snekse.github.io/test-often-and-prosper-slides/#/) that might help

All of this said, you should really refactor to make your classes easier to test.  Dependency injection is your friend. Never hardcode values in a class like that.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I was looking for.  Wondering why you used Spy v GroovySpy.  Also, why Spy v Mock or Stub?

Comment: `GroovySpy` is for special circumstances such as mocking static methods, constructors and instances who's creation you might not control.  In general, you really shouldn't needed it, but given that you were using a static method to get user categories, it was required.  That is why you shouldn't use static method - it makes mocking harder.

Comment: @CChang You use Mocks to have control over all method calls or, by default, return null from a method.  Use a Spy when you want to use the _real_ method implementation of a class for most things, but you want to override and/or verify a method for a real implementation. I never use stubs. There's also rarely a need to use Spy.